# Urxvt and tmux - set window title

Tags: tmux, window-manager, rxvt

When I use tmux from urxvt, window title is not updated. Normally when I use just urxvt, window title is updated every time I change directory and it is in form of "$USER@$HOST:$PWD", but when I run tmux from urxvt, window title stays the same as it was before running tmux.

I have tried different set terminal-overrides in tmux.conf as suggested in some answers I found on google, but none worked.

Has anybody managed to make it work? I use Xmonad as WM, but same config works if I run tmux from xterm (title changed accordingly to set-titles-string in tmux.conf), so I guess that tmux and urxvt does not really understand each other.

Versions of software:

> rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.21 - released: 2014-12-31
>
> tmux 1.9

My dotfiles:
https://github.com/overlordtm/dotfiles

Answer (score 0):

`tmux` looks at the terminal description to see if it can set the title:

- if the terminal description has the ncurses extended capability `XT` **or**
- if the terminal description has the terminfo capabilities `fsl` and `tsl` (from- and to-status-line).

ncurses' terminfo database has defined `XT` for xterm entries for some time ([since 2010](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20100925)); there is a discussion of the criteria for that in the ncurses database in [Screen Extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_S_C_R_E_E_N__Extensions_).

Only occasional entries might define the other capabilities for urxvt. If *you* did not modify the entry, it probably does not include fsl/tsl. The discussion in the terminal database explains [why fsl/tsl are not recommended](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_sl):

```
# These building-blocks allow access to the X titlebar and icon name as a
# status line.  There are a few problems in using them in entries:
#
# a) tsl should have a parameter to denote the column on which to transfer to
#    the status line.
# b) the "0" code for xterm updates both icon-title and window title.  Some
#    window managers such as twm (and possibly window managers descended from
#    it such as tvtwm, ctwm, and vtwm) track windows by icon-name. Thus, you
#    don't want to mess with icon-name when using those window managers.
#
# The extension "TS" is preferable, because it does not accept a parameter.
# However, if you are using a non-extended terminfo, "TS" is not visible.
xterm+sl|access X title line and icon name,
        hs,
        dsl=\E]0;\007, fsl=^G, tsl=\E]0;, TS=\E]0;,
```